# Foreign Key may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths - EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

This is my first ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with EF. I want to make FK `PersonalId` on `UserDetail` and `Menu`, however, from multiple iterations my final attempt is below but I'm still unable to find the issue.

These are the models:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public UserDetail? UserDetail { get; set; }

    public int PersonalId { get; set; }
    public string? Password { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PersonalId { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User? User { get; set; }

    public UserDetailsRole Role { get; set; }

    public string? FullName { get; set; }

    public Menu? Menu { get; set; }
}

public class Menu
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PersonalId { get; set; }

    public int UserDetailId { get; set; }
    public UserDetail? UserDetail { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string? Monday { get; set; }
    .....
}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(u => u.UserDetail)
            .WithOne(ud => ud.User)
            .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.PersonalId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>()
            .HasOne(m => m.UserDetail)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Menu>(m => m.PersonalId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetail>()
            .HasOne(ud => ud.User)
            .WithOne(u => u.UserDetail)
            .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.Id)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_UserDetails_Users_UserId' on table 'UserDetails' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Update-Solved:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOne(u => u.UserDetail)
            .WithOne(ud => ud.User)
            .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.PersonalId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .IsRequired(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetail>()
            .HasOne(u => u.Menu)
            .WithOne(ud => ud.UserDetail)
            .HasForeignKey<Menu>(u => u.PersonalId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .IsRequired(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetail>()
            .HasOne(u => u.Transit)
            .WithOne(ud => ud.UserDetail)
            .HasForeignKey<Transit>(u => u.PersonalId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .IsRequired(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is my first Web API .Net 6.0 application with EF. I want to make
> FK PersonalId on UserDetail and Menu, however, from multiple
> iterations my final attempt is below but I'm still unable to find the
> issue.

[image]

Actually,[this is officially known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete). On top of this, We have two ways to handle this scenario therefore, the error:

**1. Change one or more of the relationships to not cascade delete.**

In this scenario, we could make the `User` relationship with `UserDetail` and `Menu` optional by giving it a nullable foreign key property: for instance we can do something like:

```
.IsRequired(false);
```

**Note:** You can check our [official document for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#required-and-optional-relationships)

**2. Configure the database without one or more of these cascade deletes,
then ensure all dependent entities are loaded so that EF Core can
perform the cascading behavior.**

Considering this approach we can keep the `User`, `UserDetail` and `Menu` relationship required and configured for cascade delete, but make this configuration only apply to tracked entities, not the database: So we can do somethng like below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasOne(u => u.UserDetail)
        .WithOne(ud => ud.User)
        .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.PersonalId)
        .IsRequired(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>()
        .HasOne(m => m.UserDetail)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<Menu>(m => m.PersonalId)
        .IsRequired(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetail>()
        .HasOne(ud => ud.User)
        .WithOne(u => u.UserDetail)
        .HasForeignKey<User>(u => u.Id)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
        .IsRequired(false);
}
```

**Note:** As you may know `OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);` or `ClientCascade` allows the `DBContext` to delete entities even if there is a `cyclic ref` or `LOCK` on it. Please read the [official guideline for more details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete#configuring-cascading-behaviors)

Comment: Is it with a specific EF version or it's a general issue? I followed your steps but it still doesn't work. Err: may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

Comment: Its a general issue for entity framework core regardless of version.  You can set  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade) for menu and user as well because when a user  deletes then related menu and userdetails should be deleted as well. But the point is, to get rid of this error we should set `.IsRequired(false);`

Comment: .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict) this solved the problem

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and I have also updated my answer as well but yes `.IsRequired(false);` is the key point to resolve this kind of error.